# How do I scan a file that is uploaded in Contact Form 7 Plugin - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have contact form 7 plugin activated on my WordPress website.
There is an upload field added to the contact form.
Now when anyone uploads any file in the upload field and submits the form I need to scan that file to be sure there's no malware and then send it as a mail.
Can anyone suggest me ways to achieve this in WordPress.

In case anyone wants to see the Contact Form below is the code:

```
<div> 
   <div>[file* Resumeupload limit:2000000 filetypes:.pdf|.doc|.docx class:upload]</div>
   <div class="cell">[submit "Send"]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Have you found any solution to this? Please share details if you happen to get any idea or way to scan files in contact form 7. Thank you